# Implementing django-rest-passwordreset to React Native

Tags: django, react-native

I'm trying to add change password functionality to a Django / React app. I'm using [django-rest-passwordreset](https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-change-password-and-reset-password#comment-513) library for creating Reset or Forgot Password API using Django Rest Framework.

After I type the email that registered, I've managed get the token from the console
[image]

But I'm struggling to find a way to send an email to their email address with the link to reset their password along the given token. I've tried the [SMTP Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setup-sending-email-in-django-project/) or [SendGrid](https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-send-email-in-django). Was trying [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839705/djanog-with-react-how-to-reset-user-password-by-sending-user-an-email) and [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055768/how-to-add-change-password-functionality-to-django-react-app)

Can someone show me the correct way to make this work? Thanks a lot.

Edit :

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',
]
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/password_reset/', include('django_rest_passwordreset.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
]
```

Models.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.urls import reverse
from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created
from django.core.mail import send_mail  


@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):

    email_plaintext_message = "{}?token={}".format(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-request'), reset_password_token.key)

    send_mail(
        # title:
        "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Astect"),
        # message:
        email_plaintext_message,
        # from:
        "astect@asei.co.id",
        # to:
        [reset_password_token.user.email]
    )
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have wrote so far to accomplish your task and specify your issue specifically.

Comment: Hey, I've provided the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this

```
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    
    # send an e-mail to the user
    context = {
        "current_user": reset_password_token.user,
        "username": reset_password_token.user.username,
        "email": reset_password_token.user.email,
        "reset_password_url": "{}?token={}".format(
            instance.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("password_reset:reset-password-confirm")),
            reset_password_token.key,
        ),
    }

    # render email text
    email_html_message = render_to_string("email/user_reset_password.html", context)
    email_plaintext_message = render_to_string("email/user_reset_password.txt", context)

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        # title:
        "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Pinper"),
        # message:
        email_plaintext_message,
        # from:
        "<youremail>",
        # to:
        [reset_password_token.user.email],
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

And create a template like this

```
....
....
<body>
    <h1>Reset password for {{current_user}}</h1>
    <h4>You write your message</h4>

    {{ reset_password_url }}

</body>
```

The template receive a context with some variables: current_user, username, email, reset_password_url .